# Android app with login from Database

Tags: android, authentication

I have database for players of our club.

I want to create app for that.

For example each player has a username and password and one Admin only.

An admin can add new players.

so this is my Login Activity

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:padding="10dip" >         <!--  View Title Label -->
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
>         android:text="LOGIN"
>         android:textSize="25dip"
>         android:textStyle="bold" />       <!--  Email Label -->
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Email" />       <!--  Email TextField -->
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>           <!--  Password Label -->
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
>         android:text="Password" />        <!--  Password TextField -->
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:password="true" />
>
>     <!--  Error message -->
>     <TextView android:id="@+id/login_error"
>               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>               android:textColor="#e30000"
>               android:padding="10dip"
>               android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>   <!--  Login Button -->        
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
>         android:text="Login" />
>
>     <!--  Link to Registration Screen -->
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

can anyone help me? How do I **link the application with the database**

Thank you.

Comment: All of your code is that? Did you code a web service?

Comment: No only this code login

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly your login activity. Thats your layout file. Your login activity would be the java file that extend Activity.

Basically you have to do the following.

On your button click, you have to grab the username and password from your edit text, make sure they are not empty or invalid. Then you would spin an AsyncTask that would make a request to your application server via an API. PHP, ASP, Ruby on Rails. Whatever you decide to use. Your application server would then make a request to the database and log the user in.

Retrofit https://github.com/square/retrofit is a great library to make REST based requests to the server.

During this time you can show the user a progressDialog to show that he is waiting for results back.

Once the results are back, you can then log the user into the app or show an error for invalid password or email.